# Is it possible to create a radial gradient under a google map (v3) marker?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm wondering how to go about creating a radial gradient that goes from solid at the center to transparent at the outside and place it under a marker on a google map. Would it need to be a new "marker" on a layer underneath?

Comment: I am assuming you need a dynamic radial gradient so using a static image is not a possibility?

Comment: Eventually it will need to be dynamic, but static is good for now too.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can use a static image, you have to define its geometry when adding them because the default is unlikely to be what you want. Oh, I did not make a transparency so the marker will look odd over land.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/DRfuR/1/

Comment: It's a good try, but i really need the gradients to be much larger and on the layer underneath so that they cannot overlap the other marker pins.

Comment: Maybe you could add a mockup image of what you are trying to accomplish. Your original question seems like Heitor Chang's response would be correct albeit not a dynamic gradient version.

Comment: You ask, I deliver. This clearly shows the larger (78x78) gradient does not cover a neighboring marker. http://jsfiddle.net/DRfuR/4/ Google maps automatically places markers and shadows on different "panes". As for dynamic images, my page isn't ideal. My idea is to rewrite the url as you require different images. For example, this placekitten.com generates X by Y images based on the URL. See here http://jsfiddle.net/DRfuR/2/